# C++ cast pointer to base class pointer for virtual method call

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
struct A 
{
    virtual void foo() {std::cout << "A\n";}
};

struct B : public A 
{
    virtual void foo() {std::cout << "B\n";}
};

void bar(A * a) 
{
    a->foo(); 
}
```

Without changing this code, is it possible to cast `bp` pointer to B, so calling `bar` would print "A"?

```
int main()
{
    B * bp = new B();
    bar(/* do somethig*/ bp);
    return 0;
}
```

Tried every cast I remebered:

```
int main()
{
    B * bp = new B();
    
    bar((A*)bp);
    bar(static_cast<A*>(bp));
    bar(reinterpret_cast<A*>(bp));
    bar(dynamic_cast<A*>(bp));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could bypass virtual dispatch using `a->A::foo();`.  Otherwise, you'd need to do `A a = *bp;` then `bar(&a);`

Comment: Not suitable solution for me. I don't want to change `bar` function. In other cases I want to use it with virtual dispatch. I want to somehow modify the argument.
And don't want to create new object.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. In particular, it sounds like you might be mildly misunderstanding the correct role of virtual functions and the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: No, the pointer cannot be cast to anything, in order to have the described results. This goes down to how C++'s virtual inheritance works on a fundamental level, C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a shim wrapper around `B`, and have the shim's virtual function dispatched to `BWrap::foo()` call directly to `A::foo();`.

There's not really any point in the example to carrying along the `B&` member variable reference, but for more interesting examples there may be a use case.

```
struct BWrap : public A
{
    B& b;
    BWrap(B& bb) : b{bb} {}
    virtual void foo() { b.A::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    B* bp = new B();
    BWrap bw{*bp};
    bar(&bw);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on the `A` object being a base class subobject of a `B` object and on not modifying the first code snippet at all, then the only solution is to add an even more derived class that can override the virtual call as explained in the answer by @Eljay (which I completely forgot to think about when first writing this answer).

Other options are to create a complete `A` object, not a `B` object, or to modify `bar` to do a call without virtual dispatch by using a qualified name:

```
a->A::foo();
```

All of the casts you are showing have the same effect as the implicit conversion, except for `reinterpret_cast` which will cause undefined behavior when used this way.